# Phantomjs protractor angular 2 localhost error

Tags: angular, selenium, phantomjs, protractor

I've got some troubles with using protractor with phantomjs browser, it cannot connect with local server, any other url works. 
There is some code:
protractor.config.js

```
var suites = {
    // e2e: "./e2e.js",
    // e2e2: "/e2e-spec.ts"
};
var helpers = require('./helpers');
require('ts-node/register');
exports.config = {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001',
    specs: [
        helpers.root('src/e2e/e2e.js'),
        helpers.root('src/e2e/e2e-spec.ts')
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'phantomjs',
        version: '',
        platform: 'ANY'
    },
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true
    },
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
};
```

And ofc spec file:

```
    it('should put email click button etc', () => {
//this one take about:blank url            
      browser.driver.get('http://localhost:3001/student/panel').then( function () {
                browser.driver.sleep(5000);
                browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()
                    .then((url) => {
                    console.log(url);
            expect(url).toEqual('hhttp://localhost:3001/student/panel');
                })
            ;
        });
    });
    it('should get into 10 minute mail page', () => {
        minuteMail.getNew().then(function () {
//this works well
            browser.driver.sleep(1000);
            browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()
                .then((url) => {
                    expect(url).toEqual('https://www.10minutmail.pl/?newMail=1');
                })
            ;
        });
    });
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you try using `http://127.0.0.1:3001/student/panel`?

Comment: 1. Does this work in Chrome? As in, does this actually work in a browser. 2. Have you considered using headless Chrome? PhantomJS is no longer being supported.